# Stack Overflow Email Settings Don't Work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, email, profile-page

All settings in my Stack Overflow account for Edit email settings are returning 403 error responses. Meaning I can't unsubscribe from any of their emails.

Comment: Unable to repro now, probably fixed?

Comment: Correct, it now looks as though it has been fixed.